# Is there a way to connect 2 computers with a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, connection, psexec

I know there is something called PsExec but you need to have it installed on both of the computers or something.

Is there any other way to be able to connect/send messages/commands between 2 computers, and if not, then how can I do it with PsExec?

Comment: you don't need psexec on both machines.Only on the current one.

Comment: If you don't want to install additional programs you can use `SCHTASKS` or `WMIC PROCESS`